# Entry cannot be cast to javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I keep getting the JAXB cast error.

I'm not sure what to correct at this point.

The unmarshalling:

```
try{
        Client client = Client.create();
        client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(API_KEY, ""));
        WebResource webResource = client.resource("https://url.entries.xml");
        webResource.setProperty("", API_KEY);
        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/xml").get(ClientResponse.class);

        if(response.getStatus() != 200){
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
        }

        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println("\n============getFtoCResponse============");
        System.out.println(output);


        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Entries.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

        Entries itsEntries = (Entries)((JAXBElement)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(output))).getValue();


    /*  Object o = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(output));
        System.out.println(o.getClass());*/

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here are the first 16 lines from my Entry.java class, I have annotated setters and getters:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Entries")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entry {


    private String DateCreated;
    private String EntryId;
    private String Field1;
private String Field2;
private String Field3;
private String Field4;
```

And here is my Entries class, to be used to get a list of Entry objects:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Entries")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entries extends Object {

    @XmlElement(name="Entries")
    private List<Entry> entryList = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    @XmlElement(name="Entries")
    public List<Entry> getEntryList() {
        return entryList;
    }


    public void setEntryList(List<Entry> entryList) {
        this.entryList = entryList;
    }

}
```

Error Message:

> Entry cannot be cast to javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement

**Question Update**

Entries:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Entries")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entries {

    @XmlElement(name = "Entries")
    private List<Entry> entryList = new ArrayList<Entry>();


    public List<Entry> getEntryList() {
        return this.entryList;
    }


    public void setEntryList(List<Entry> entryList) {
        this.entryList = entryList;
    }

}
```

Entry:

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entry {

```
private String DateCreated;
private String EntryId;
private String Field1;
private String Field2;
private String Field3;
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Entries>
<Entry>
<EntryId>1</EntryId>
<Field3>John</Field3>
<Field4>Doe</Field4>
<Field12>21 jump street</Field12>
<Field14></Field14>
<Field15>USA</Field15>
<Field11>USA</Field11>
</Entry>
</Entries>
```

Comment: No more errors, with the updates above, but my entryList is empty?

Comment: I had to rollback your change otherwise your initial question doesn't make any sense. If you want to update your answer to add your progress, don't remove the initial content (otherwise your question and the answers will then be outdated) simply append your progress at the end of the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can see you have several issues in your current code. The second issue listed here is the root cause of your exception.

#### 1. Not the right class provided to `JAXBContext.newInstance(Class)`

You are supposed to provide the class of the root element which seems to be `Entries` in your case so it should be `JAXBContext.newInstance(Entries.class)`

#### 2. The way you extract the `Entries` instance

The expected code is rather this:

```
Entries itsEntries = (Entries)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(output));
```

This is actually the reason why you get this exception, as `unmarshal` provides directly the type corresponding to the root element not a `JAXBElement` as you seem to expect.

#### 3. The mapping is not correct

Up to now in the class `Entries`, `Entries` is mapped twice on the field `entryList` and on the method `getEntryList()` which is not correct as you need to map it only once, since you set the annotation `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`, you are supposed to annotate only the field.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Entries")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entries {

    @XmlElement(name="Entries")
    private List<Entry> entryList = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    public List<Entry> getEntryList() {
        return entryList;
    }
```

The second issue is the fact that you have 2 classes `Entry` and `Entries` that are mapped with the exact same element's name using the annotation `@XmlRootElement(name = "Entries")` such that JAXB cannot know which class to use when it finds a root element whose name is `Entries`, in your case the class `Entries` is the only root element so the annotation should be set on this class only. The mapping of the class `Entry` is already defined on the mapping of the field `entryList` such that you have no need to set this annotation on the class.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entry {
    ...
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "Entries")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entries {
    ...
}
```

The third issue is related to the fact that you don't map properly the elements `Entry` in the class `Entries` which is actually the reason why you have an empty list when you try to unmarshal your `XML` content, the correct mapping is:

```
@XmlElement(name="Entry")
private List<Entry> entryList = new ArrayList<Entry>();
```

#### 4. No need to extend `Object`

Assuming that you are referring to `java.lang.Object`, you have no need to make your class `Entries` extends `java.lang.Object` as it is implicit.

Comment: Thanks. I made the changes, I get no errors now. Only problem is my entryList is empty. not sure why there is no data. I'll update my original post with the updated code.

Comment: please provide your XML

Comment: 1. why did you remove the mapping on the field entryList? 2. Don't set the annotation XmlRootElement on the class Entry as explained in my response update

Comment: For me your list is empty because of the fact that you have no more mapping on the field entryList

Comment: the updates I made have me back to an old error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"Entries"). Expected elements are (none)

Comment: please add the XML to your question

Comment: response updated, please check again especially the end of point #3

Comment: the added info to step 3 solved it. I appreciate your patience. It was a bit hard following you the way things were worded. Thanks again! public class Entries {

 @XmlElement(name = "Entry")

Comment: which part(s) of my answer is hard to understand? I can try to reformulate if needed

Comment: you were spot on with the technical info. my problem was the little subtleties. Like "The expected code is this:", then you show my bad code. Again, not the technical stuff, just the nuances and sequence of info. It's All good !

Answer (score 1):

Change  jaxbcontext instantiation to
JAXBContext.newInstance(Entries.class);

Comment: "Entry cannot be cast to javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement"